# What is the meaning of colon in $resource object in angular / ionic framewrok

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am taking a course which shows a service using the following line of code .

```
return $resource(baseURL+"dishes/:id",null, {'update':{method:'PUT' }});
```

I wonder what is the meaning of colon above before "id " . It does not work if we paste the URL as given . In my case like " http://localhost:3000/dishes/:id" in the browser .

Comment: May need to spend some time with the docs.  The :id indicates a parameter in the url.  In this case, likely an id for the object being updated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer may be found by [reading the fine manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)

Comment: Thanks Phil for sharing the manual. It shows the question is topical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:id` indicates the id that you can set dynamically when you are updating the object.

for example, if we want to set id as `123`,

```
return $resource(baseURL+"dishes/:id",{id:123}, {'update':{method:'PUT' }});
//                                     ^ set id attribute like this
```

now when you query above resource, you'll be accessing your url as

```
// PUT: /some/base/url/dishes/123
```